# Save DataFrame in Python as csv and upload it on AWS S3 with public access

Tags: python, amazon-web-services

After preparing a bunch of DataFrames in python I would like to directly save it on Amazon AWS.

My code ends with something like:

```
new_output_csv = pd.read_csv("C:/Users/output.csv")
...
new_output_csv.to_csv("C:/Users/output1.csv", index=False)
```

I tried:

```
import boto3

session = boto3.Session(
    aws_access_key_id='xxx',
    aws_secret_access_key='yyy',)
s3 = session.resource('s3')
s3.meta.client.upload_file(Filename='C:/Users/output1.csv', Bucket='test1234542', Key='output1.csv')
```

Unfortunately, it seems that the boto module is not working.

I am using python 3.7.

It is also neccessary, that the file has public access because another service is grapping the updated file every day...

Best
Michi

Answer (score 0):

Is it giving you an error or is the file just not appearing in S3?

The very simple version of uploading a file to a bucket is to get the bucket itself and use the upload_file method:

```
import boto3

session = boto3.Session(
    aws_access_key_id='xxx',
    aws_secret_access_key='yyy'
)

s3 = session.resource('s3')
bucket = s3.Bucket('test1234542')
bucket.upload_file('C:/Users/output1.csv', 'output1.csv')
```

Answer (score 0):

I think this is enough.

```
import boto3

s3 = boto3.resource('s3', aws_access_key_id='xxx', aws_secret_access_key='yyy')
s3.Bucket('test1234542').upload_file('C:/Users/output1.csv', 'output1.csv')
```

---

If you want to make the object as public read, then you can use `ObjectAcl` and `put` command, see the [documentation](https://boto3.amazonaws.com/v1/documentation/api/latest/reference/services/s3.html#S3.ObjectAcl.put).

```
object_acl = s3.ObjectAcl('bucket_name','object_key')
response = object_acl.put(
    ACL='private'|'public-read'|'public-read-write'|'authenticated-read'|'aws-exec-read'|'bucket-owner-read'|'bucket-owner-full-control',
    AccessControlPolicy={
        'Grants': [
            {
                'Grantee': {
                    'DisplayName': 'string',
                    'EmailAddress': 'string',
                    'ID': 'string',
                    'Type': 'CanonicalUser'|'AmazonCustomerByEmail'|'Group',
                    'URI': 'string'
                },
                'Permission': 'FULL_CONTROL'|'WRITE'|'WRITE_ACP'|'READ'|'READ_ACP'
            },
        ],
        'Owner': {
            'DisplayName': 'string',
            'ID': 'string'
        }
    },
    GrantFullControl='string',
    GrantRead='string',
    GrantReadACP='string',
    GrantWrite='string',
    GrantWriteACP='string',
    RequestPayer='requester',
    VersionId='string'
)
```

The Grants Type should be defined, i.e. Group and the other things are options. You might need ACL to public-read.

Comment: Hi. Nice, that works fine. Only problem is the permission. Is there a way to get public access already in the python code? At the moment i have to go manually to the bucket, click on the folder "Permissions",click on "Public Access" and then make a tick at "Read object"

Answer (score 0):

I solved it:

```
s3 = boto3.resource('s3', aws_access_key_id='xxx', aws_secret_access_key='yyy')
s3.Bucket('test1234542').upload_file('C:/Admin/final1.csv', final1.csv', ExtraArgs={'ACL':'public-read'})
```